# Convert stringified data class to data class Object Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, parsing, serialization, deserialization

I have a data class converted to string using

```
network.toString()
```

Result:

```
Network(addressRegex=^(0x)[0-9A-Fa-f]{40}$, memoRegex=, memo=false, network=ETH, enabled=true, withdrawMin=14.0, withdrawFee=7.03)
```

I want to convert it to Network Object, is there any way to do it?

```
data class Network( val addressRegex: String?,
                    val memoRegex: String?,
                    val memo: Boolean?,
                    val network: String)
```

Thanks!!

I could not do anything, as I did not find same problem on Internet

Comment: There is no reverse conversion for this in Kotlin. You would have to manually program the String parsing and conversion. For this kind of task, what is typically done is to use a JSON library to covert the object to a JSON String, and then you can convert it back using the JSON library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what are your exact requirements, or the level of modification access you have to that log you extracted (it seems that the log and the Network data class you have are different). However, it's possible to parse what you have like so:

```
data class Network(
    val addressRegex: String?,
    val memoRegex: String?,
    val memo: Boolean?,
    val network: String
)

val stringNetwork = "Network(addressRegex=^(0x)[0-9A-Fa-f]{40}$, memoRegex=, memo=false, network=ETH, enabled=true, withdrawMin=14.0, withdrawFee=7.03)"

// Please note that this is a very naive/fragile approach...
val network = stringNetwork
    .substringAfter("(")
    .split(",")
    .map { it.split("=") }
    .associate { it[0] to it[1] }
    .mapKeys { it.key.trim() }
    .mapValues { it.value.trim() }
    .let {
        Network(
            it[Network::addressRegex.name],
            it[Network::memoRegex.name],
            it[Network::memo.name]?.toBoolean(),
            (it[Network::network.name] ?: error("Network is required"))
        )
    }

println(network)
// => Network(addressRegex=^(0x)[0-9A-Fa-f]{40}$, memoRegex=, memo=false, network=ETH)
```

However, I agree with @Tenfour04, if you have access to that `Network` object, it would be better to rely on a more concrete format/structure (i.e. JSON) and then safely deserialize / serialize it using a library like: [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#introduction-to-serializers)

Comment: Watch out for any of those String properties containing commas or equals signs.